# Separate a transparent layer from this image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background-removal, barcodes

I have this image :

[image]

As you can see It has a transparent layer of QR Code and I need to extract It somehow..

**How can I do this?**

I tried selecting the QR Code using color range.

[image]

but as you can see It was an unsuccessful attempt.

Comment: Most of a QR code isn't needed in most situations. You have almost all of the code on the left and top which holds most of the data. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1d/QR_Code_Structure_Example_3.svg/800px-QR_Code_Structure_Example_3.svg.png If all fails, try to at least recover the top and left area and as much of that corner of the image as possible as data is read into the code from left to right, top to bottom. Most likely, the information in the bottom right corner is error checking.

Comment: How many of these do you have to do? Just one? Or a whole bunch?

Comment: Just this one. Anyways I did it by HAND DRAWING the QR Code! It was 5 hours of torture...

Comment: It would be easier if this wasn't a jpeg, the compression artifacts are a bit nasty. In this was a uncompressed png then thsi would have been easy. Now its a bit tricky but i think i have solved this

Comment: Ok you need to do this in multiple passes, copy layer blur subtract get best pixels this is result layer (kind of like frequency sparation). Hide result (repeat until you find good blur amount). do same with different blur on inverse, fill with black merge to result. Hide result Do a laplace or fourier separate frequencied eliminate and add to result. now your really close...

Comment: Here is first pass http://i.imgur.com/9birO25.png this could be done far better if i would write a custom filter kernel based on pixel identification

Comment: I wouldn't even begin to do this with Photoshop. I'd regenerate the QR code using the information it supplies. Photoshop is *not* always the best route.

Comment: @Scott How am I supposed to regenerate the given QR code? ( in other words "I do not know the decoded message of the given QR code" ) **Given** that First Image I need to remove the background or in other words extract the QR code from that image. My solution was to hand draw all the individual pixels that match the given QR code.

Comment: iDoky... use a QR reader.. see what the information is.. Plug that same information into a QR generator to generate the same QR code without the background image. It seems rather straight-forward to me. If you need the QR code, surely you have contact with the person responsible for display it. Worst case is you **ask** the client what the QR Code is supposed to generate. (This QR code appears to load a URL asking the user to install some DIY service App -- while it works, I'd NEVER install an app based on a QR code).

Comment: You were able to read this QR code as is? I thought the whole point of extracting this QR code from the image is to be able to decode it with a QR reader? Oh and there is no way for me to 'contact the person responsible'.

Comment: It took some patience but yes, my iPhone QR reader eventually picked it up. It's not *easily* read, but I did get it to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you go online and google "QR code generator", there are several sites that will generate a QR code for free. Type in the URL which the QR code refers to, i.e. "www.company/webpage" and tell it to create the code, and you can download the QR code as a clean vector file. Some of them will even let you specify the size of the code (1", .5", etc) and the color (black, white, etc). I think it is safest to stick with a code that is at least 3/4" in size (newer cell phones can read smaller QR, but older cell phones still need the bigger size). I would do this rather than try to painstakingly pick the code off its background....

PS I only know this because I had to set up a QR code on a brochure recently!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but this isn't quite what I was looking for. This was a Photoshop question as you see the tag 'adobe-photoshop'.

Comment: oh, sorry! New to Stack Exchange. did not notice tag!

Comment: oh, sorry! New to Stack Exchange, did not notice Tag. (Redrawing the QR does seem like torture, thought the online code generators could help you avoid that step!) Anyway, hope your project works out well.